# make XML pretty

Tags: xml, formatting, format, pretty-print

I have a lot XML files, but all are in one-three lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sldLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" type="picTx" preserve="1"><p:cSld name="Picture with Caption"><p:spTree><p:nvGrpSpPr><p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/><p:cNvGrpSpPr/><p:nvPr/></p:nvGrpSpPr><p:grpSpPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/><a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
```

Everythings looks like code above.

How to make it pretty? After each `>` new line. I tried to install to my VSCode Prettier and other XML Formatters, but nothing helped.

Do you know any settings which should i set/

Answer (score 0):

On Windows for XML formatting I prefer to use Notepad++ with XML Tools plugin by Nicolas Crittin.
After installing the plugin from *Plugins/Plugins Admin...*, click *Plugins/XML Tools/Pretty print* or just use **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+B**, or **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A** if you want to indent attributes too.
If you use x86 or x64 based Linux or macOS (pre-Catalina), I think you can run Notepad++ with the use of [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/about). (I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an Intel-based laptop and I can run Notepad++ with Wine.)
See the output of your code below:
[image: Pretty XML]